# pgfmathprintnumber in bold and/or sans serif

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfmath

I've set some pgfkeys such as `precision=2` and `use comma`. Now I wonder how do I get the results of

```
\pgfmathprintnumber{123.567}
```

to be bold and/or sans serif?

I thought this is easy, but everything I find online is just concerning plots, and does not work for me.

Comment: A good answer to your question heavily depends on what you are doing: could you post an example starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regular text formatting doesn't apply to math mode and `\pgfmathprintnumber` inherently uses `\ensuremath` behind the scenes around the number. You can turn it off via

```
\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{123.567}
```

Then it will assume that it is already in the math mode and won't modify the number printing. That means the number will be interpreted as regular text.

But I recommend keeping the math mode and (changing the math font) or (using `\mathbf{}` type of math font modifiers).

Comment: ah ok, did not know that it uses `\ensuremath`. thanks.

Comment: additionally, how would one change the font size `\pgfmathprintnumber` prints?