# Conditional formatting, rounding and postprocessing of a column in pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, formatting, conditionals, pgfplotstable

I want to round p-values in a table to two decimals (for example 0.05), have values less than 0.05 in bold font and have values less than 0.01 to come out as '<0.01' in bold font. Like this (the example is made in Excel):

[image]

**Question:** How do I do this using `pgfplotstable` package?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={var,p},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=[0.5ex]\bottomrule},
columns/var/.style={string type,column name=Variable},
columns/p/.style={column name=$p$,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2,dec sep align},
]{
var p
A   0.0445
B   0.5343
C   0.0000
D   0.0254
E   0.9843
}
\end{document}
```

Which gives following table with correct rounding:

[image]

I manage to get values <0.05 to come out as bold font, but for some reason I do not manage to round the values. Rounding works for the values that are >0.05 (i.e. `\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}` works, but `\textbf{\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}}` produces scientific notation without bold font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={var,p},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=[0.5ex]\bottomrule},
columns/var/.style={string type,column name=Variable},
columns/p/.style={column name=$p$,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2,
  postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.initial={}{%
       \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,0.05))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
           \textbf{##1}
           \else
           \pgfmathprintnumber{##1}
                \fi
      },
    },
  },
]{
var p
A   0.0445
B   0.5343
C   0.0000
D   0.0254
E   0.9843
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also fail to incorporate both bolding and `<0.01` into the script. If I run the script with `<0.01` condition, I get scientific notation for values that are between 0.01 and 0.05 and correct rounding for values that are >0.05.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={var,p},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=[0.5ex]\bottomrule},
columns/var/.style={string type,column name=Variable},
columns/p/.style={column name=$p$,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2,
  postproc cell content/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.initial={}{%
       \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,0.01))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
           \textbf{$<$0.01}
           \else
           \pgfmathprintnumber{##1}
                \fi
      },
    },
  },
]{
var p
A   0.0445
B   0.5343
C   0.0000
D   0.0254
E   0.9843
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Bonus niceness:** It would be cool to get the values centered by decimal point, but I guess this is impossible, because **`<0.01`** probably has to come out as a string?

Comment: Please see this one for the bold/regular issue http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119299/pgfmathprintnumber-in-bold-and-or-sans-serif/119301#119301

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that. Both of the following after `\ifnum\...` produce errors: `\mathbf{\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}}`, `\pgfmathprintnumber{\mathbf{##1}}`. Even `\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}` gives a weird result (scientific notation). There must be something wrong with this line:  `/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.initial={}{%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Working from one of your attempts, and adding the following:

- [`bm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bm) package for a bolder `<` symbol
- conditionals for both p<0.01 and p<0.05

gives a final document of:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tabularx,booktabs,bm}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={var,p},
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=[0.5ex]\bottomrule},
  columns/var/.style={string type,column name=Variable},
  columns/p/.style={column name=$p$,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2,
  postproc cell content/.style={
    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.initial={}{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,0.01))}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    $\bm{<0.01}$
  \else
    \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,0.05))}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
      $\mathbf{\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=2]{##1}}$
    \else
      \pgfmathprintnumber{##1}
    \fi
  \fi
      },
    },
  },
]{
var p
A   0.0445
B   0.5343
C   0.0000
D   0.0254
E   0.9843
}
\end{document}
```

I'm not certain if having the bold numbers slightly misaligned compared to the normal numbers is a problem or not.