# pgfplotstable - Conditional row formatting

Tags: formatting, conditionals, pgfplotstable

I am using the package pgfplotstable to create and typeset several large tables. My challenge is to make several rows bold conditional on the value of a variable in my data.

After searching, reading and testing, I have managed to get a column bold, a cell bold and a row bold (first, last and specific), but not conditional on a variable's value.

In the small example below, I want the rows where ID = 1 to be bold:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep= semicolon ,
    sci zerofill
]{
A;B;C;ID 
1;4;2;0 
2;1;6;1 
3;6;1;1 
4;2;3;1 
5;1;9;0 
6;4;2;0
}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

I did not include any formatting in the example above. Hence, I have added some more details in the MWE below. **The follow-up question is how do I keep the formatting specified before making the specified rows bold?**

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs, ifthen}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep= semicolon]{
A;B;C;ID 
C00;100;0.9;0
C01;31;16.9;1
C03;46;1;1 
C04;62;0.3;2 
C05;18;1.9;1 
C06;69;2.0;1
}\mytable

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
fixed,
fixed zerofill,
precision=0,
set thousands separator={}
} 

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = semicolon,
    columns = {A, B, C, ID },
    columns/A/.style={ string type, column type = {l}},
    columns/B/.style={ column type = {r}},
    columns/C/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
    columns/ID/.style={ column type = {r}, precision = 1},
    every column/.style={
        postproc cell content/.append code={
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{ID}\of{\mytable}
            \ifthenelse{ \pgfplotsretval < 2 }{
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\bfseries##1}
            }
            {
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1}
            } 
        }
    }
    ]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See [Conditional formatting, rounding and postprocessing of a column in pgfplotstable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156168/110998).

Answer (score 6):

Here is one possibility to do it.

- Read the inline table into a macro using `\pgfplotstableread`, in order to be able to reference the elements in the table using `\pgfplotstablegetelem`.
- `\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]3}\of{\mytable}` returns the value of the fourth column (= column with index 3) of the current row (stored in `\pgfplotstablerow`) in the macro `\pgfplotsretval`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs,ifthen}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep= semicolon]{
A;B;C;ID 
1;4;2;0 
2;1;6;1 
3;6;1;1 
4;2;3;1 
5;1;9;0 
6;4;2;0
}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    sci zerofill,
    every column/.style=
     {assign cell content/.code=
       {\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{[index]3}\of{\mytable}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{1}}%
          {\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\bfseries##1}}%
          {\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1}}%
       }
     }
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```