# Conditionally use bold font for table cell with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, pgfplotstable

I am trying to conditionally use bold font for table cells with values according to a condition. It works nicely with changing the text color as illustrated in the example below, but I am not able to use bold font instead. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
index error
1   2.50000000e-01
2   0.0
3   1.56250000e-01
4   3.90625000e-01
5   0.0
6   2.44140625e-01
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  percent type/.style={
          column type=r,
          precision=1,
          preproc/expr={100*##1},
          postproc cell content/.append style={
              /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{~\%},
          },
          fixed,
          fixed zerofill,
          postproc cell content/.append code={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\valueIn
            \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\valueIn}%
            \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
            \let\value=\pgfmathresult
            \ifdim \value pt = 0 pt%  if value is zero
              \begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand
                          \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\color{gray!75}
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
                          }}\temp
            \fi
          }
      },
  columns/error/.style={percent type}
  ]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

This example results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119299/3235 ?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. How would I use the answers in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119299/3235 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way of doing this, but it does not seem to be the optimal solution to me. The required source code to conditionally use bold font in pgfplotstable is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
index error
1   2.50000000e-01
2   0.0
3   1.56250000e-01
4   3.90625000e-01
5   0.0
6   2.44140625e-01
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  percent type/.style={
          column type=r,
          precision=1,
          preproc/expr={100*##1},
          % postproc cell content/.append style={
%               /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{~\%},
%           },
          fixed,
          fixed zerofill,
          postproc cell content/.append code={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\valueIn
            \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\valueIn}%
            \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
            \let\value=\pgfmathresult
            \ifdim \value pt = 0 pt%  if value is zero
              \begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand
                          \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\boldmath
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}~\noexpand\textbf{\%}}}\temp
            \else
              \begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand
                          \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}~\%}}\temp
            \fi
          }
      },
  columns/error/.style={percent type}
  ]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]