# How to highlight pgfplotstable cells with bold font while preserving number format?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to highlight cells in my pgfplotstable, but the bold font setting overwrites my number format. How to prevent this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
      col sep=comma,    
      every row 1 column 1/.style={
        postproc cell content/.style={
          @cell content=\textbf{##1}
        }
      },
      fixed,fixed zerofill,
      precision=1,
      multiply with=100,  
    ]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]

Comment: this is a duplicate somewhere

Comment: @percusse I didn't find an exact duplicate. I tried to customize [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201444/conditionally-use-bold-font-for-table-cell-with-pgfplotstable?rq=1) approach but failed, as it is conditional to the whole table and inserted new cells when applied to a selected cell...

Comment: *it's *formated why can't I edit my bounty description? ;)

Comment: @fmetz - Have a look at sergej's answer to this question of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253897/pgfplotstable-postproc-cell-content-resets-style-of-cell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just replace  `@cell content=\textbf{##1}` with `@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}`

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
      col sep=comma,    
      every row 1 column 1/.style={
        postproc cell content/.style={
          @cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}
        }
      },
      fixed,fixed zerofill,
      precision=1,
      multiply with=100,  
    ]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is the one combination I did not try... :D Would you mind looking at my other open [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272725/how-to-only-truncate-pgfplotstable-integer-entries-but-not-rounded-floats), too? Thanks in advance.