# How to only truncate pgfplotstable integer entries, but not rounded floats?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a csv file conaining differently precise numbers. Now i want to plot them with `precision=1`. The reader should see that some values are integers, so the respective number should be shown without decimal places, but numbers that are rounded to a zero fractional digit should be shown with a trailing `0`.

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
81
81.0234
81.4520
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
      col sep=comma,
      zerofill,
      precision=1,  
    ]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

**Is there a general number format in pfgplotstable that only truncates the fractional digit from the first `81` to indicate the missing precision in the raw data?**

I tested different number formats from the [PgfplotsTable manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf) but didn't find a solution.

Comment: search for `int detect`

Comment: I did, but then the scientific format is chosen.

Comment: Ah yes, you need to preproc it with the `\pgfmathisint` stuff. I'll try to look at it later in case it's not answered yet.

Comment: @percusse I hope you'll find the time to think of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro which detect integer is`\pgfmathprintnumber@INT@DETECT` defined like this

```
\def\pgfmathprintnumber@INT@DETECT#1{%
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1}%
    \pgfmathfloat@to@FMeE@style\pgfmathresult
    \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@INT@DETECT@issci\pgfmathresult\relax
}
```

If the input number is an integer no period is displayed at all. If not, the scientific format is chosen.

To change this and use fixed format instead of scientific you can change the macro `\pgfmathprintnumber@INT@DETECT@issci` which is defined like this

```
\def\pgfmathprintnumber@INT@DETECT@issci#1#2e#3\relax{%
    \begingroup
    \ifnum#1<3\relax
        \pgfmathfloatcreate{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\pgfmathfloat@round@precision@=\pgfmathfloat@round@precision
        \def\pgfmathfloat@round@precision{6}%
        \expandafter\pgfmathroundto\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\pgfmathfloat@round@precision=\pgfmathfloat@round@precision@
        \ifpgfmathfloatroundhasperiod
            \pgfmathprintnumber@SCI@issci#1#2e#3\relax
        \else
            \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}#1#2e#3\relax
        \fi
    \else
        \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle#1#2e#3\relax%
    \fi
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
    \endgroup
}
```

With this

```
\def\pgfmathprintnumber@INT@DETECT@issci#1#2e#3\relax{%
    \begingroup
    \ifnum#1<3\relax
        \pgfmathfloatcreate{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\pgfmathfloat@round@precision@=\pgfmathfloat@round@precision
        \def\pgfmathfloat@round@precision{6}%
        \expandafter\pgfmathroundto\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\pgfmathfloat@round@precision=\pgfmathfloat@round@precision@
        \ifpgfmathfloatroundhasperiod
        \expandafter\pgfmathroundtozerofill\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}
        \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}#1#2e#3\relax
        \else
            \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}#1#2e#3\relax
        \fi
    \else
        \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle#1#2e#3\relax%
    \fi
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
    \endgroup
}
```

**And your code become**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathprintnumber@INT@DETECT@issci#1#2e#3\relax{%
    \begingroup
    \ifnum#1<3\relax
        \pgfmathfloatcreate{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\pgfmathfloat@round@precision@=\pgfmathfloat@round@precision
        \def\pgfmathfloat@round@precision{6}%
        \expandafter\pgfmathroundto\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
        \let\pgfmathfloat@round@precision=\pgfmathfloat@round@precision@
        \ifpgfmathfloatroundhasperiod
        \expandafter\pgfmathroundtozerofill\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}
        \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}#1#2e#3\relax
        \else
            \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}#1#2e#3\relax
        \fi
    \else
        \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle#1#2e#3\relax%
    \fi
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
81
81.0234
81.4520
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
      col sep=comma,
      precision=1,
      int detect,
      ]{data.csv}    


\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think a switch to define the output format should be added to pgfplotstable.

Comment: `int detect` is defined with `pgf` not in `pgfplotstable` exactly in the file `pgfmathfloat.code.tex`.

Comment: Christian Feuersänger is the author of both. Essentially `pgfplots` turns on `fpu` library by default.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can catch the entries and format them independently depending on whether they are integers or not.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
  int or print/.style={
    preproc cell content/.append code={%
      \pgfmathifisint{##1}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pgfretval}{\pgfretval}%        
        }{%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,#1}%
        }%
      \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\pgfretval}%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
    col sep=comma,
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    int or print={sci,sci zerofill,precision=7}%Choose what the float should look like
    ]{
81
81.0234
81.4520
81.0000
81.00000001 % See the precision
}
\end{document}
```

[image]